# graphql-java query returns null for endpoint that accepts user input as filter

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I am working with Netflix Dgs with springboot to handle my queries. My resolver accepts a filter as an input. My goal is to be able to find a patient based on patient name and service name (for now, will update to validate with patient DOB), and have the AlternativeMedicine type be returned, which shows the patient and what service within alternative services the patient belongs to. I'm not sure if the fact that I am using faker to generate the data is what's causing it to return null....I wonder if actually storing data in a db to verify against might help. I am also using codegen to help with generating the resolver, though I am giving it some tweaks. I tried using the Datafetcher but it throws an error about being unable to map to my child type Patient that is also in the filter. to Code is as follows:

```
type AlternativeMedicine {
    service: [String]
    description: String
    patient: Patient // there exists a Patient type, see the DAO for how Patient data is created
}

input AlternativeMedicineFilter {
    service: String
    patient: PatientFilter
}

input PatientFilter {
    name: String
    medicalRecordNumber: Int
}

type Query {
alternativeMedicine(alternativeMedicineFilter: AlternativeMedicineFilter): [AlternativeMedicine]
}

// DAO
@Configuration
public class FakeAlternativeMedicineDAO {
    public static final List<AlternativeMedicine> ALTERNATIVE_MEDICINE_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    private Faker faker;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() throws MalformedURLException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var pcpLocations = new ArrayList<Address>();
            var patientAddress = Address.newBuilder().street(faker.address().streetAddress())
                    .city(faker.address().city())
                    .state(faker.address().stateAbbr())
                    .zipCode(faker.address().zipCode())
                    .build();
            for (int j = 0; j < ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4); j++) {
                var pcpLocation = Address.newBuilder().street(faker.address().streetAddress())
                        .city(faker.address().cityName()).state(faker.address().stateAbbr())
                        .zipCode(faker.address().zipCode())
                        .build();
                pcpLocations.add(pcpLocation);
            }

                var patientPcp = PrimaryCareDoctor.newBuilder()
                        .name(faker.name().fullName())
                        .locations(pcpLocations)
                        .emailAddress(faker.name().lastName() + "@mail.com")
                        .build();
                var patient = Patient.newBuilder().name(faker.name().fullName())
                        .medicalRecordNumber(faker.random().nextInt(3000))
                        .address(patientAddress)
                        .gender(String.valueOf(faker.gender()))
                        .contactNumber(String.valueOf(faker.phoneNumber().phoneNumber()))
                        .primary(patientPcp)
                        .build();
                var alternativeMedicine = AlternativeMedicine.newBuilder()
                        .service(randomAlternativeMedicineGenerator())
                        .description(faker.lorem().characters(20))
                        .patient(patient)
                        .build();

                ALTERNATIVE_MEDICINE_LIST.add(alternativeMedicine);

            }

    }
    private List<String> randomAlternativeMedicineGenerator(){
        switch (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(16) % 5){
            case 0:
                return List.of("Chiropraxy");
            case 1:
                return List.of("Accupuncture");
            case 2:
                return List.of("Osteopathy");
            case 3:
                return List.of("Homeopathy");
            default:
                return List.of("Osteopathy", "Chiropraxy");
        }
    }


} 

// resolver
 @DgsQuery(field = "alternativeMedicine")
    public List<AlternativeMedicine> getAlternativeMedicine(@InputArgument AlternativeMedicineFilter alternativeMedicineFilter) {
        if (alternativeMedicineFilter == null) {
           // System.out.println("filter is empty");
            return FakeAlternativeMedicineDAO.ALTERNATIVE_MEDICINE_LIST;
        }
       System.out.println("filter is full " + alternativeMedicineFilter); //successfully prints out filter input

        return FakeAlternativeMedicineDAO.ALTERNATIVE_MEDICINE_LIST.stream().filter(
                alternativeMedicine -> this.matchAlternativeMedicineFilter(alternativeMedicineFilter, alternativeMedicine)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

// validates input data against an instance of AlternativeMedicine (again, its not actually stored anywhere yet, I'm using faker right now)

    private boolean matchAlternativeMedicineFilter(AlternativeMedicineFilter filter, AlternativeMedicine alternativeMedicine){
        // 1 check if service matches with service we have on record
        var isServiceMatch = StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(filter.getService(),
                StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(alternativeMedicine.getService().toString(), StringUtils.EMPTY));
        if(!isServiceMatch){
            return false;
        }

        // 2 validate patient input data
        // TODO - add validation for patient MRN as well
        // realistically patients are verified via DOB, name and MRN
        // basically - if the patient name filter includes the actual patient's name

        // check MRN
//        if(!filter.getPatient().getMedicalRecordNumber().equals(alternativeMedicine.getPatient().getMedicalRecordNumber())){
//            return false;
//        }
        //  var isPatientMrnMatch = filter.getPatient().getMedicalRecordNumber().equals(alternativeMedicine.getPatient().getMedicalRecordNumber());
        var isPatientNameMatch = filter.getPatient() != null && StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(filter.getPatient().getName(),
                StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(alternativeMedicine.getPatient().getName(), StringUtils.EMPTY)
        );
        if(!isPatientNameMatch){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

// testing in altair

query alternativeMedicine($alternativeMedicineFilter: AlternativeMedicineFilter){
  alternativeMedicine(alternativeMedicineFilter: $alternativeMedicineFilter){
     service
    description
    patient {
      name
      medicalRecordNumber
      address {
        street
      }
      gender
      contactNumber
      primary {
        name
      }
  }
}
}

// variables
"alternativeMedicineFilter":{
    "service": "Osteopathy",
    "patient":{
      "name": "loralee",
      "medicalRecordNumber": 1658
    }
```

I tried the datafetcher but it seems like I am unable to map my data correctly when I am trying to access the Patient scalar type which exists on the filter as well.